# Why the property does not pass to another view Controller?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, didselectrowatindexpath

```swift
extension ReservationViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "restaurantDetail") as?  RestaurantViewController {
            vc.restaurantNametxt = searchRestaurant[indexPath.row].restaurantName
            print(searchRestaurant[indexPath.row].restaurantName)
        }
        print(indexPath.row)
        print(searchRestaurant[indexPath.row].restaurantID ?? "")
        restaurantsTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "restaurantDetail", sender: self)
    }
}

class RestaurantViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var restaurantName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var reserverButton: UIButton!
    
    var restaurantNametxt: String = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        restaurantName.text = restaurantNametxt
        print(restaurantNametxt)
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func reserverButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "FinalStep", sender: self)
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }
}
```

When the user performs `didSelectRow at` I want to pass `searchRestaurant[indexPath.row].restaurantName` to another vc which is `RestaurantViewController` but on UILabel is still "".

`vc.restaurantNametxt` contains the real restaurantName because it is printing the value.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach fails because you do not use the vc you instantiated. With `performSegue` you create a new ViewController that gets presented. And its property is empty as you already discovered.

Try:

```
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and remove:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "restaurantDetail", sender: self)
```

Comment: Yeah it works but it opens next view controller Modally as a new layer. Not like a navigation controller with back button on top.

Comment: @BranislavFekeč please update your question to include all requirements you have for this. It´s hard to compile an apropriate answer without the information how this is structured and what should and should not happen.